# Nested Loop PHP

Tags: php

i have code :

```
<?php
$number =9;
$number2 = $number / 2;
    for ($b=0; $b<=$number2; $b++){
        for ($i=$number; $i>=1; $i--){
            echo $i;
        }
        echo "<br/>";
        for ($a=1; $a<=$number; $a++)
        {
        echo $a;
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```

I want the result like this .

```
987654321
123456789
987654321
123456789
987654321
123456789
987654321
123456789
987654321
```

why if i put odd number like 9 , why always the result 10 loop ?

Comment: Because loop is starting from `0` so total iterations `0,1,2,3,4 ` that's 5 times and you have two inner loops so 5*2 = 10 loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two loops in a loop, therefore you'll always get an even number of lines.

You don't actually need that structure, see:

```
$number=9;
$k=0;
$sum=1;
for($i=1; $i<=$number; $i++) {
    for($j=1; $j<=$number; $j++) {
        $k+=$sum;
        echo $k;
    }
    echo '<br>';
    //Sum once again so in the next iteration $k is 0 or 10
    $k+=$sum;
    //Invert the sign of $sum so in the next iteration it substracts, and then adds, and so on
    $sum*=-1;
}
```

Also note that going from `0` to `$number` *inclusive* (lower or equal comparation) you'll get one iteration more (from 0 to 9 there are 10 whole numbers).

Comment: @ZakarioLesrahmanto - If it worked for you, you should accept the answer so other users know it's been solved.

Comment: Hi magnus , the result its start 123456789 . i want first row is 987654321 , how i get it ?

Comment: Start from `$k=10` and `$sum=-1`. Analyze the code, it's really simple!

Answer (score 0):

Solve with this code , thx Gabriel.

```
$number=9;
$k=0;
$sum=1;
for($i=1; $i<=$number; $i++) {
    for($j=1; $j<=$number; $j++) {
        $k+=$sum;
        echo $k;
    }
    echo '<br>';
    //Sum once again so in the next iteration $k is 0 or 10
    $k+=$sum;
    //Invert the sign of $sum so in the next iteration it substracts, and then adds, and so on
    $sum*=-1;
}
```

Comment: I didn't do anything to help you. It was all Gabriel. And I must say that it's quite disrespectful towards Gabriel (who was nice enough to spend his time helping you) to post his answer as your own instead of  accepting his.

Comment: Actually, I see that you haven't accepted _one single answer_ on _any_ of your questions, though you got plenty of answers. That's _very_ disrespectful. If people take their time helping you, you could at least recognize it.

Comment: i'm sorry for not concentrating, in here it so late night , now in my country is 3AM . T_T

Comment: ...and still you haven't accepted Gabriels answer. =/